# Why does Django add a dollar sign in my URL pattern? (NoReverseMatch)

Tags: django, django-forms, django-urls

I spent my entire day trying to fix this bug and I have no idea how to do it. I am trying to create a new markdown file and redirect the user to the new page after submitting the form. I tried to change the URL name, tried to change variable names but nothing works. The problem may be the fact that Django adds a dollar sign in my URL pattern but I am not sure about it because I have tried to give the URL the value of an existing page. I would appreciate a detailed explanation for this problem.
my views.py:

```
def entry(request, entry):
    entryPage = util.get_entry(entry)
    if entryPage is None:
        message = messages.warning(request, 'There is not a page with this name.')
        return render(request, 'encyclopedia/error.html', {
            'entryTitle': entry,
            'message': message
        })
    else:
        return render(request, 'encyclopedia/entry.html',{
            'entry': markdowner.convert(entryPage),
            'title': entry
        })

def new(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get the form
        form = Post(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Clean the form
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            lower_title = form.cleaned_data['title'].lower()
            text = form.cleaned_data['textarea']
            entries = util.list_entries()
            # Check for existing entry
            for entry in entries:
                if lower_title == entry.lower():
                    message = messages.warning(request, "There is already a page with this name.")
                    context = {
                        'message': message,
                        "form": Search(),
                        "post": Post()
                    }
                    return render(request, 'encyclopedia/new.html',context)
            # Create and redirect to new entry
                else:
                    util.save_entry(title,text)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("entry", args=[title]))
    else: 
        return render(request, 'encyclopedia/new.html', {
            "form": Search(),
            "post": Post()
        })
```

The error I receive:

```
NoReverseMatch at /new
Reverse for 'entry' with arguments '('NewTitle',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['entry$']
```

My urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:entry>", views.entry, name="title"),
    path("new", views.new, name="new"),
    path("error", views.error, name="error"),
    path("entry", views.entry, name="entry")
]
```

Also when I check the local vars inside the Django Traceback, I don't see the title from. This may be caused because the iteration is executed just once until the error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add a parameter for the `entry` to your entry URL pattern:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # …,
    path('entry/<str:entry>/', views.entry, name='entry')
]
```